# Make [retagging] and [addtag-request] synonyms to [retag-request] rather than [tags]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, meta, synonym-request

Currently here, on meta.SO, [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) and [addtag-request](/questions/tagged/addtag-request) are [synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tags/synonyms) to [tags](/questions/tagged/tags).

But `[retagging]` should be a synonym to [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request), and `[addtag-request]` to [tag-creation](/questions/tagged/tag-creation).

Comment: Downvoter, be so kind to comment. Why on earth do you object?!

Comment: Actually, [meta-tag:addtag-request] should be synonymized with [meta-tag:tag-creation] instead.

Comment: @animuson: Sure, updated. Thanks!